# Is it possible to gather parameters from multiple funtions?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

error: 'number2' was not declared in this scope nr3(number, number2); ... is this even possible, for this type of function to work, parameters from multiple functions?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void nr1();
void nr2(int& number);

void nr3(int& number, int number2) {
  int number3 = 6;
  cout << number + number2 + number3 << endl;

}

void nr2(int& number) {
  int number2 = 7;
  cout << number + number2 << endl;
}

void nr1() {
  int number = 1;
  nr2(number);
  nr3(number, number2);
}

int main() {
  nr1();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "gather parameters"? Where should `nr1` get `number2` from?

Comment: `nr2` has something called `number2` in its definition, but that's a detail of the definition. It has not decided to share that value with anyone else, which it might do by returning a value or assigning to another reference parameter.

Comment: No, forcing developers to read through every single function to find where a variable comes from would make every codebase nigh-impossible to reason about in any meaningful way.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now. Thanks to everyone I guess.

Comment: If you want the same variables to be accessible to multiple functions, you can bundle them together in a class and have them use class variables, or you could write some global variables that they access. But there isn't a way to just tell the function `nr1` about a variable local to the function `nr2`.